# JList into a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextarea

Okay, this is my first project(bank application) in JAVA, and all I want is to display the results taken from a database and set it into a JTextArea. However, I want the bank clerk to be able to click on a line in the JTextArea and do certain actions(I will take care of that once I get the results in the JTextArea); that's why I'm using a JList. I have gotten to the point that I was able to show the results in the JTextArea without using the JList. My question is:

- If possible, how can I put a JList into a JTextArea?

Here is part of my code:

```
// function that will search for a record in the database
private void searchRecord(){


    try {

        Connection connect = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "url";
        String user = "user";
        String password ="password";

        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

        Statement SQLStatement = connect.createStatement();
        String select = "SELECT * FROM customerinfo WHERE LastName LIKE '"+ txtSearch.getText().trim() +"%'";
        ResultSet rows = SQLStatement.executeQuery(select);

        while(rows.next()){

            textArea.setLineWrap(true);

            String first = rows.getString("FirstName");
            String last = rows.getString("LastName");
            String middleInitial = rows.getString("MiddleInitial");
            String[] row = {first, last, middleInitial};
            list = new JList(row);
            list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            //textArea.append(row[1].toString() + ", " + row[0].toString() + " " + row[2].toString() + ".\n");
            textArea.append(list values goes here + "\n"); // here is where I'm stuck!!!
            //System.out.println(rows.getString("LastName"));
        }
```

Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: You can loop through the list's items and append them to the JTextArea. What happens when you've tried this? Where does your code fail, and how does it fail?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, you might actually try something, as opposed to (effectively) coming here and asking others to do it for you.  BTW - it seems the list will only ever have on `ResultSet` row in it.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, why are you apparently creating a new JList with each iteration of your while loop? Wouldn't it make much more sense to make the JList once, before the while loop, or even in the class's constructor?

Comment: Well, I have tried list.getSelectedValue() or list.getSelectedValue().toString() and I get null values. Also, I have tried list.toString, and I get a bunch of string values that are not from the database. Also, I thought that since list is an array(right?), I tried something like list[0].toString, but that didn't work out pretty good.

Comment: duh...didn't think about that Hovercraft...so I have to put the JList out of the while loop, correct?

Comment: @Andrew....I actually don't want anybody to help me, but I have been on this issue for about a week; I have tried changing the code several times without success. Like I said before, I'm learning JAVA on my own, and I'm not sure what you are asking me about the ResutSet.

Comment: 1) 1st thing to learn - it is Java, not JAVA.  2) *"tried changing the code several times without success"*  O_o Several times?  Try reading some documentation/tutorials and changing it several dozen times. 3) I was saying basically the same as HFOE. 4) *"I actually don't want anybody to help me"* So.. why did you ask a question?

Comment: @Andrew...trust me, I have done more than several times...it was a way of saying. The reason why I'm asking is because I'm stuck and without a clue. I looked online, but there is not a single thing about Jlist in JTextarea. I looked for videos and still couldn't find a thing about it. If you do have a link or video about it please provide some. Thank you!

Comment: @user1183022: of course there's nothing online about this because it's a very specific and narrow combination of questions. There's lots of information though about getting information from JLists and likewise about putting information into JTextAreas. I'm still not sure where you're stuck, or what it is exactly you're trying to do. What do you mean by putting information from JList into JTextArea, when it really appears that you're adding to both the list and the text area at the same time in your while loop. Please clarify your question greatly.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to fetch data from the database in store it in a JList. After, I want to show the results in a JTextArea. Now, you might be wondering why I want to store the info in a JList and then show it in JTextArea, right? Well, I want to be able to select a line in the JTextArea and trigger an event, so I thought JList is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @user118: That is still confusing because a JList is built precisely for just this: selecting a line triggers an event, whereas JTextArea would require some code gymnastics to get this effect. I still don't see the utility of your using a JTextArea in addition to a JList.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need a JTextArea?

Comment: Okay....I will try without a jtextArea...thank you!

Comment: @user118: yes, try without a JTextArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Dont put list to JTextArea.You can put data into directly

String first = rows.getString("FirstName");
String last = rows.getString("LastName");
String middleInitial = rows.getString("MiddleInitial");


JTextArea txaDetails=new JTextArea();
txaDetails.append("\n"+first +last +middleInitial +"\n");
txaDetails.setCaretPosition(txaDetails.getDocument().getLength());
```